# Unexpected character ('A' (code 65)): was expecting a colon to separate field name and value\n

Tags: javascript, json, rest

I am very new in JSON and I found this error when parsing some code from REST API

```
{
"date":"2017-11-08T09:37:51+0900",
"customer_id":"24243",
"device_name":"10.342.93.193",
"running_status:"Active"
}
```

apparently the character 'A' here is the problem because it was just working fine when only put "date" "customer_id" and "device_name". Any suggestion to overcome this issue?

Comment: The responded JSON is malformed. Notice how it's missing a colon before the word `Active`.

Answer (score 3):

This just a typo.

You're missing a quote after `"running_status`.

The object should look like this;

```
{
    "date": "2017-11-08T09:37:51+0900",
    "customer_id": "24243",
    "device_name": "10.342.93.193",
    "running_status": "Active"
}
```

Comment: JavaScript **Object** Notation. It's a string that represents an object, so calling it either an object or a string is technically accurate.

Comment: It's a **Notation** based on JavaScript Objects. JSON is a serialization format and has nothing to do with JS objects.

Comment: If you honestly think that delineation is important or useful in helping the user comprehend my answer - then feel free to edit my answer. Otherwise, I'm not sure why you think this important enough for debate.

Comment: Often beginners tend to use the name "JSON objects" which is wrong and misleading. Using the correct terminology in answers is important to clarify that distinction.